# Can I use the "AS" word in and update with all recent versions of SQLite?

Tags: sqlite

I am executing this query:

```
UPDATE PHRASE AS P SET F1 = 0, F2 = 0, F3 = 0, F4 = 0, F5 = 0 WHERE Hidden = 1 AND P.JLPT = 5
```

and getting this message:

[image]

Does anyone have any advice they can offer. The table phrase is just and ordinary table and the reason for coding in the "AS" was because I am using a where clause generated for another use case. So far when I try  it myself the statement works okay so I am wondering  why a user with an iPhone X and a recent OS could be getting this problem. Not sure if this makes any difference but the user is from France and so may be using a French version of the iOS.

Comment: What version of sqlite are you using? It works in 3.30.1...

Comment: I don't have that information as it was from a users phone.